# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, content-security-policy

I am not much familiar with CSP so posting here.

I am getting the below error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'sha256-P/4RbWZ5tavHlZH3S2JukJ4toJ9iLwFkiBGYsngpgqo=' 'sha256-i4JIH9RhDp81FOGH3ZwoQRt2R4uvOYyeOmkCZoX6HeY=' 'sha256-3VlFnxIhSKloUaebh7I+Yjnu9vwMuwGEuqykqBQQLNw=' 'sha256-GHjvsztQyqr0koa6RWaeYUhRgrR/WcXa+NGlCwEpcLY=' 'sha256-3W2JH/z3DpHtF9okrA6TIFaJ6wFrL4gfTXfK5fjo1V0=' ssl.google-analytics.com [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com) [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) connect.facebook.net". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AchpXWJVta1Kal3dZ49Zq4Or0DgNsfAgebn6LioP0Zo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="calendar_10">
                        <img id="cal_date" class="datepicker" src="calendar.gif" alt="Pick a date.">
                    </span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Calendar.setup({
                            inputField  : "element_10_3",
                            baseField   : "element_10",
                            displayArea : "calendar_10",
                            button      : "cal_date",
                            ifFormat    : "%B %e, %Y",
                            onSelect    : selectDate
                        });
                    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, an error comes from the inline javascript Calendar.setup

can anyone help me with this

Comment: I assume you have no control over the CSP header. Looks like your service provider doesn't want you to be able to add your own scripts.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to achieve these things?

Comment: If there was, CSP would suck. What the CSP does allow is serving arbitrary script files from `'self'`. So placing your JS in an  external file and serving it from the same domain as the HTML would work.